# why the multi line text field got strike through in alert mail of sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have created an alert on a sharepoint custom list as immediate alert.when i modify the field of multiple line of text then in alert email i get the both previous as well as the current  item value strikethrough .
can some one help me out why this is happening?

the alert works fine for the single line of text field.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to resolve the issue :

1. Go to alerttemplate.xml file located at `"C:\Program Files\Common
   Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\XML\"`
2. Keep the copy of `alerttemplate.xml` for backup.
3. Edit original alerttemplate.xml file.
4. Depending on your listtype make the limit length 1000. (if list is custom list edit the line under `GenericList` and so on)

   ```
   <Limit Len="1000" AutoHyperLinkNoEncoding="TRUE" MoreText="...">
          <GetVar Name="OldValue#{Field}" />
    </Limit>
   ```
5. iisreset

Shukraj Khadse
L&T Infotech | Vashi, Navi Mumbai | India